# How do I make my java tests run consecutively with SBT

Tags: java, sbt

I have a java project that is built with SBT. Currently my integration tests are running concurrently and causing each other to fail, even though if I run them separately they're fine. Does anyone know how to make my tests run consecutively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add this option to your SBT build file:

`parallelExecution in Test := false`

You can find the relevant documentation here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Parallel-Execution.html